# OrientDB ETL: Looking for efficient work-around for lack of edge: skipDuplicates option

Tags: etl, orientdb

I tried the transformation { "edge" : { "class":"my_edge","skipDuplicates":true } }...then noticed the documentation had it in as of version 2.2. (4 releases from now!?)

I'm a bit stuck on a viable work-around. I have a single flat file i'm trying to break out into about 5 different objects. (things you have to deal with when you get data from end users).

I'd hoped the skipDuplicates option on the vertex would by-pass the remaining transforms, but no such luck.

Is there a block or command work-around I can use. I don't think a sql lookup would work, since other edges from that batch would not have been committed yet.

By the way, I've also noticed when i tried to hack the edge index, i ended up in some kind of infinite loop...

Thanks for any assistance.

**Update with example**
-I'm using 2.1.8

here's the basics of the configuration

```js
    {
        "transformers" : [
             { "merge": { "joinFieldName":"Document_ID", "lookup":"Article.Document_ID" } },
             { "vertex": { "class": "Article" , "skipDuplicates":true } },
             { "edge": { "class":"belongs_to", "skipDuplicates":true, "direction":"out","joinFieldName": "Journal_ID", "lookup":"Journal.Journal_ID", "unresolvedLinkAction":"CREATE"} },
            ...
         ]
    }

//and of course, I've listed the classes and indexes within the orientdb loader
    "classes":[
        { "name":"Content", "extends":"V" },
        { "name":"Article", "extends":"Content" },
        { "name":"belongs_to", "extends":"E" }
    ],
    "indexes": [
        {"class":"Article", "fields":["Document_ID:string"], "type":"UNIQUE" }
    ]
```

Comment: Can you share a sample file and your configuration? And which version of OrientDb are you using?

Comment: Hi Lindsay, the skipDuplicates option is available on 2.1.8 too. I'll update the docs. If it isn't working as expected, you can help me with a full configuration, a sample csv and what kind of results do you want ? it would be very appreciated. I know it is difficult to extrapolate sample data from your real application, but it will speed up my work a lot. Cheers, RF